# I started virtualenv on Mac OS, then unable to deactivate it completely

Tags: macos, virtualenv

I started virtualenv on my Mac OS, using the commands

```
python -m virtualenv envsp
source env/bin/activate
```

Then it was successfully activated.

Then I entered `exit`, and I got a response which says

```
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And I could not type anymore.

So, I opened another terminal and tried basic commands such `ls` `rm` `nano`, now it keeps saying

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

I am not sure what have I done. And I can't seem to find any solution to this. So if anyone has any clue about this. Please Please Please help!

One more important information `cd` command works however.

Comment: Can you try logging out and logging back in?

Comment: how do I logout and log back in?

Comment: I mean log out and log back in on MacOS, nothing to do with the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You mixup `exit` of the shell and `deactivate` of virtualenv. If you activate a python virtualenv and you want to continue using the shell, then enter `deactivate`. If you are done for the day with your shell, then `exit` it.

Comment: As of now I added `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` this line on top of my .bash_profile. Things are working again. But what is the better way to resolve this?

Comment: You seem to have lost bash initialization files like .bash_profile and .bashrc